# how to integrate chrome search engines with a quick launch app like alfred

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, search, alfred

## intro

I use [alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) to quick launch pretty much everything on my mac. I also use chrome [custom search engines](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630963?hl=en) to quickly search for example jira/github issues etc..

so for example if a typical github issue for a specific project (let's give that project a VIB abbreviation) looks like this

```
https://github.com/my-org/my-project/issues/15
```

then i configure chrome custom search engine so that when i type `VIB` in the url, it appears like so t[image]

typing 15 makes me jump to that link

[image]

## question

Is there a way to make this happen on alfred? (or any other quick launch app like alfred.. I recall seeing some of my colleagues years ago use this on a quick launch app on PC)

So this is what the scenario will look like (using [gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin)):

`given` user taps keyboard shortcut to launch alfred
`and` alfred search field shows up
`when` user types in vib + <kbd>tab</kbd> on alfred
`then` alfred becomes a search engine for that project
`and` user can type in the issue number and hit enter
`and` alfred takes the user straight to that issue page on chrome, the same  result that would happen if the user used a chrome search engine

## update

I came across this [script](https://gist.github.com/hijonathan/3836026) which does exactly what i want (even better than [this workflow](https://github.com/gharlan/alfred-github-workflow) since it involves less typing), however in alfred 3 doesn't have this path:

```
Alfred/customsites/customsites.plist
```

any idea what I should replace it with?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with `workflow` feature of Alfred. For that, you must have to purchase `powerpack` to use `workflow`.

There is one 'workflow' that do the similar thing. see below link.

https://github.com/gharlan/alfred-github-workflow

You can modify this `workflow` after downloading it.

Comment: see update, your solution works but it's not exactly what i need

Comment: @abbood script is over 4 years old and things are changed, better to use standard way. just read workflow documentation. it's easier and doesn't use the hack like the script you found. also, this will provide future compability.